# Multi files upload using curl to ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, file-upload

I'm struggling about how I can send an unknow number of files to my rails app using curl.

This is my curl request to POST with one file :

`curl -H 'Authorization: Token token=your_token' -X POST -F job[webapp_id]=2 -F job[file]=@test.txt localhost:3000/api/v0/jobs`

It works.

I would like to allow  the user to send as much as file as he wants with something like :

`-F job[files][]=@test1.txt -F job[files][]=@test2.txt`

`-F job[files[]]=@test1.txt -F job[files[]]=@test2.txt`

But it's not working.
I also tried with :

`-F job[files[0]]=@test.txt -F job[files[1]]=@test2.txt`

Still not working. I think it's because I don't know how to tweak my permit parameters. I get an empty array.

Any idea on how to do it with one request ?

Comment: Do you have to use curl?

Answer (score 0):

[RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) may be easier to work with.